# How to change soure control from TFS?

Tags: tfs

I have a solution say it Myproject in vs2010. I have create a solution folder on TFS say it $/Myproject and checked in all source code files.

Now I have created another folder on TFS say it $/Myproject2 and I want to the solution Myproject in VS 2010 to connect to $/Myporject2.

I guess I should disconnect from TFS and then connect to  $/Myproject2 and check in all codes, but not sure how.

So I try to go to workspace->Edit Wokrspace, and change the Source Control Folder in the list. Is it right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Map your workspace to $/ and you'll be able to access both `$/Myproject` and `$/Myproject2`

However, I don't recommend having one team project be able to reference another team project.  If you're going to have these types of dependencies, I would have a layout more like this:

```
$/MySolution
     MyProject
           Project.csproj              
     MyProject2
           Project2.csproj
```

Where "MySolution" is the master product you are trying to build.